# Titanium: Network connection was lost

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

I'm getting a weird error.

Trying to download an mp3 file using createHTTPClient.

The file downloads fully, and at the very end gives the Network connection was lost error.

If i download the same file using a regular browser, the file downloads and has the same file size as the one downloaded with the createHTTPClient.

Anyone have any idea what can be causing this?

```
var c = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient({enableKeepAlive:false});
c.setTimeout(10000);
c.ondatastream = function(e){
    Ti.API.info(e.progress)
};
c.onerror = function(e){
    Ti.UI.createAlertDialog({title:'XHR', message:'Error: ' + e.error}).show();
};

c.open('GET','http://asd123:r2d2@http://178.62.197.233/dl/110/ac33f71d7db3c3a0fdb80d90dbc95c7a15c6281f4e32a123c948c7467e421b28/128/');

c.file = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, 'myfile.mp3');
c.onload = function(e){
    Ti.API.info('Loaded!...')    
};
c.send();
```

Comment: Try giving timeout of more than 10 seconds and let me know the results

Comment: So i set the timeout to c.setTimeout(10000000);

Comment: Still same error...
Even tried playing with the headers: c.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/force-download');

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so turns out Titanium was not at fault here, the server was not sending content type and content size headers which was causing Titanium to freak out once the download was done.

Setting those headers fixed the issue.